# Execute javascript then refresch script every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have this Function

```
function ReFresh() {
    // myScript
    setTimeout('ReFresh()', 60000);
}
```

This executes myScript after 60 seconds but I do not want that. What I want is to execute  myScript immediately and then repeat myScript every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So call `ReFresh` manually:

```
function ReFresh() {
    // myScript
    setTimeout(ReFresh, 60000);
}
ReFresh();
```

Also avoid using string as argument for `setTimeout`, pass function reference instead.

Comment: I need to refresh myScript automaticcaly

Answer (score 2):

You could use an immediately invoked function:

```
(function ReFresh() {
    setTimeout(ReFresh, 60000);
}());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnLYK/2/)

Also: try not to pass strings to `setTimeout` (sometimes known as an ["implied eval"](http://jslinterrors.com/implied-eval-is-evil-pass-a-function-instead-of-a-string)), just pass the function name.

Here's a version that uses a clearTimeout:

```
var num = 0, timer;

(function myScript() {
  if (num === 10) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  } else {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
    timer = setTimeout(myScript, 1000);
  }
}());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnLYK/4/)

Comment: This is good! Just worth mentioning that this way `ReFresh` is not available globally any more.